# Black screen post ubuntu 20.04 LTS on AMD A6-7480 Radeon R5, 8 Compute Cores 2C+6G

Tags: dual-boot, boot-repair, amd-processor

I am not able to boot and enter into ubuntu, after first time installation of 20.04 LTS version..
Its going black screen..

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ezNkVdQy59T_CrZuCoMC0DjjRqF9SUtP?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt install libnuma-dev
sudo reboot
```

-------After Reboot----------

```
sudo apt install wget gnupg2
wget -q -O - https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/rocm.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
echo 'deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/debian/ ubuntu main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rocm.list
wget -q -O - https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/rocm.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rocm-dkms && sudo reboot
```

---

Source: [ROCm Installation](https://rocmdocs.amd.com/en/latest/Installation_Guide/Installation-Guide.html)